# Mpandroidchart display values as text

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have created a pie and a line chart using [Mpandroidchart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

**Pie Chart**
[image]

**Code**

```
getEntries();
    pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries, "");
    pieDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);
    pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(10f);
    pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(5f);
    pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
    pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    pieChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    pieChart.setCenterText("Last Two Months Sale" );
    pieChart.setCenterTextSize(14f);
    pieChart.setCenterTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    pieChart.animateX(1500);
    pieChart.setData(pieData);

  public void getEntries() {
    pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(200,"March", 0));
    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(300, "April",1));

}
```

**Line Chart**

[image]

**Code**

```
 private ArrayList<Entry> lineChartDataSet(){
    ArrayList<Entry> dataSet = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    dataSet.add(new Entry(1,200));
    dataSet.add(new Entry(2,300));
    dataSet.add(new Entry(3,500));
    return  dataSet;


}
lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineChartDataSet(),"data set");
    lineDataSet.setLineWidth(1.75f);
    lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(5f);
    lineDataSet.setCircleHoleRadius(2.5f);
 iLineDataSets.add(lineDataSet);
    lineData = new LineData(iLineDataSets);
 lineChart.setNoDataText("Data not Available");
    lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    lineDataSet.setColors(color);
    lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.parseColor("#891e9a"));
    lineDataSet.setCircleHoleColor(Color.parseColor("#891e9a"));
    lineDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false);
    lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(true);
    lineDataSet.setDrawCircleHole(true);
    lineDataSet.setLineWidth(5);
    lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(5);
    lineDataSet.setCircleHoleRadius(5);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(10);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    lineChart.setPinchZoom(false);
 lineChart.getAxisLeft().setSpaceTop(40);
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setSpaceBottom(40);
    XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
 xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisLabel));
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
 lineChart.setData(lineData);
    lineChart.invalidate();
```

Both the charts are displaying but I want to change the format of the value. In both the `Pie` and `Line` charts, one can only add `floating` values. But I want to add strings.

**Example**

I want to do the following

```
pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(200,"March", 0));
```

replace with

```
pieEntries.add(new PieEntry("200K","March", 0));
```

and

```
 dataSet.add(new Entry(1,200));
```

replace with

```
 dataSet.add(new Entry(1,"200K"));
```

How can I  achieve  it ?

Any help would  be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ValueFormatter. Create ValueFormatter and then set it to the pieData

```
ValueFormatter formatter = new ValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return ((int) value) + " " + "K";
    }
};
pieData.setValueFormatter(formatter);
```

If you use `LargeValueFormatter` it automatically turn values like "1.000" into "1k", "1.000.000" into "1m" (million) e.g. To use `LargeValueFormatter` just set it to pieData.

```
pieData.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter())
```

See also https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface

Comment: `pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet); pieData.setValueFormatter(formatter);` gives me `300.0` and `200.0`

Comment: I have another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related  to it can you please see it?