# Mpandroidchart text not properly showing on x axis on line chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, x-axis

I am working on `Mpandroidchart`. I have created a  line chart and tried to place strings on my `xaxis`.

```
final ArrayList<String> xAxisLabel = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("March","April","May"));



private ArrayList<Entry> lineChartDataSet(){
    ArrayList<Entry> dataSet = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    dataSet.add(new Entry(1,40));
    dataSet.add(new Entry(2,10));
    dataSet.add(new Entry(3,15));    
    return  dataSet;


}

 lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineChartDataSet(),"data set");
 XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

    //String setter in x-Axis
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisLabel));
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
```

**Output**

[image]

In the above image, you can see that month names are not properly placed. i.e `march` is not displaying and only `april` and `may` are shown.

**Expected Output**

[image]

How can I do it?

Any help would  be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Instead of **IndexAxisValueFormatter** in MPAndroidChart version v3.1.0 you can use a custom **ValueFormatter** and override **String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis)** method where you can define your own logic to replace for each X value its corresponding String. Example based on your data Set will be like below:

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
  @Override
  public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
     String label = "";
     if(value == 1)
       label = "March";
     else if(value == 2)
       label = "April";
     else if(value == 3)
       label = "May";
     return label;
   }
});
```

And the result will be like below:

[image: chart]